# How to check the Azure Service Bus queue is empty?

Tags: python, azure, command-line-interface, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-queues

I'm using azure service bus queues in my application and here my question is, is there a way how to check the message queue is empty so that I can shutdown my containers and vms to save cost. If there is way to get that please let me know, preferably in python.

Thanks

Comment: Always use a generic [python] tag, only use a version-specific tag if your question is version-specific. If you can't fit both, always go with the generic [python] tag, if only to get more eyeballs on your question

Answer (score 2):

For this, you can use [`Azure Service Bus Python SDK`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-servicebus). What you would need to do is get the properties of a queue using `get_queue` method that will return an object of type `Queue`. This object exposes the total number of messages through `message_count` property. Please note that this count will include count for active messages, dead-letter queue messages and more.

Here's a sample code to do so:

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService, Message, Queue
bus_service = ServiceBusService(
    service_namespace='namespacename',
    shared_access_key_name='RootManageSharedAccessKey',
    shared_access_key_value='accesskey')
queue = bus_service.get_queue('taskqueue1')
print queue.message_count
```

Source code for Azure Service Bus SDK for Python is available on Github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/azure-servicebus/azure/servicebus.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the length of the messages returned from [peek_messages](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-servicebus/latest/azure.servicebus.html?highlight=peek_messages#azure.servicebus.ServiceBusReceiver.peek_messages) method on the class `azure.servicebus.ServiceBusReceiver`

```
with servicebus_receiver:
    messages = servicebus_receiver.peek_messages(max_message_count=1)
if len(messages) == 0:
    print('Queue empty')
```